# How to attach screenshot to mailcomposer in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Hi i'm using the below code to attach screenshot to mailcomposer, i'm not having a device to check so will this work on actual device?

```
-(void)launchMailAppOnDevice
{
    /*Take a SnapShot of current screen*/
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

    NSString *recipients = @"mailto:xyz@abc.com?cc=@\"\"&subject=blah!!blah!!";

    NSString *body = @"&body=blah!!blah!!";

    NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", recipients, body,  imageData];
    email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea to use "mailto"? Why not use `MFMailComposeViewController` and add the screenshot as an attachment using `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:`?

Comment: I'd be interested to see if this actually worked... Not that I'd ever use it, but it's a funny approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last 5 lines are wrong. You most likely want to use the MFMailComposeViewController class:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mcv = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

[mcv setSubject:@"blah!!blah!!"];
[mcv setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"xyz@abc.com"]];
[mcv setMessageBody:@"Blah!! 'tis the body!" isHTML:NO];
[mcv addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Screenshot.jpg"];

[someViewController presentModalViewController:mcv animated:YES];
[mcv release];
```

P. s.: don't forget to add the MessageUI framework to your project and also `#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>`.

P. p. s.: while it's important to test on an actual device, it's even more important to read some guides and documentation before writing the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png"   fileName:@"fileName"];
```

if you plan on using a `MFMailComposeViewController`, which you should use instead of mailto:, but I can't stress enough how important it is to always test your applications on a real device.

Comment: **NOTE:** H2CO3 has a better explanation on how to do this.